# {pg-promise} postgres - how to convert type int[] to be compatible with POINT()

Tags: pg-promise

So I'm using `pg-promise` to insert into a type `POINT` column. But it's giving me the following error:

```
function point(integer[]) does not exist
```

I'm passing the values as an array. What should I change to make it work?

Some code (not sure if useful):

```
simplified_query = `$${counter++}:name = POINT($${counter++})`

fields =
[
    "geolocation",
    [10, 10]
]
```

Comment: Have you tried [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting)?

Comment: @vitaly-t never saw that before. I might give it a try later, but I'm just doing a more manual insert for now: `$${counter++}:name = POINT($${counter++}, $${counter++})`

Comment: Manual query formatting is frowned upon, as it is dangerous and unreliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting), if your `field` is `['geolocation', [10, 10]]`, with the first value being the column name, you can use the following function:

```
function asPoint(field) {
    return {
        rawType: true,
        toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format('$1:name = POINT($2:csv)', field)
    };
}
```

Then you can use `asPoint(field)` as a query-formatting parameter:

```
const field = ['geolocation', [10, 10]];
db.any('SELECT * FROM table WHERE $1', [asPoint(field)])
//=> SELECT * FROM table WHERE "geolocation" = POINT(10, 10)
```

Alternatively, your `field` can be a custom-type class that implements [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting) either explicitly or via the prototype, in which case it can be used as a formatting parameter directly.